# Template Reference Variables are undefined in ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I am generating dynamic input fields using angular 6.
also validation so that i used template reference.
But it is not working.

Below is my code.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of attributeList;let i = index">
<input type="{{item.type}}" class="form-control" id="usr_{{item.type}}_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.value" name="usr{{i}}" #lastName="ngModel" required />

<div class="error-mesg" [hidden]="lastName.valid || (lastName.pristine && !form.submitted)">
    Field is required
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We don't see any code

Comment: can you please check now.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Is `attributeList` variable public in the component's ts code ?

Comment: yes it is public

Comment: @PardeepJain it is giving ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

Comment: your lastname is having null value that why it gives this error.

Comment: @AnkurShah i have passed ngModel to lastname so my model should be bind to lastname

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question partly in the comment section.

The only valid check is made on lastName. That means lastName is undefined at the moment you are executing your code.

If you are ok with it being undefined the following might work.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of attributeList;let i = index">
<input type="{{item.type}}" class="form-control" id="usr_{{item.type}}_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.value" name="usr{{i}}" #lastName="ngModel" required />

<div class="error-mesg" [hidden]="lastName?.valid || (lastName?.pristine && !form.submitted)">
    Field is required
  </div>
</div>
```

Notes the question marks it makes safe navigation possible by loading blank content if the property is not set: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths.

**Edit:**

If you wish to hide the div containing the warning under certain circumstances  I would use *ngIf to see if it is invalid. In that case you can use the ? operator.

```
<div *ngIf="lastName?.invalid || lastName?.dirty" class="error-mesg">
    Field is required
  </div>
</div>
```

Even better would be to do this type of logic inside your .ts file. This makes it more easy to unit-test the code. And use a ngIf that utilizes that function. But that is my personal preference.

Comment: In this case it will always visible. I need to bind validation on run time.

Comment: In that case you need to make sure it is set before reading the property. You are now trying to read something that is not defined.

Comment: Is your goal to only show the warning if there is something wrong?